# Hi. How do I query for the total score for each pair where the order of the pair is ignored in MySQL?

Tags: mysql, sql

```
Letter 1 | letter 2 | Score
-----------------------
A        | B        | 5
B        | A        | 6
C        | D        | 9
D        | C        | 7
```

In this case , I want find the total score for (A,B) which is 5+6=11 & the total score for (C,D) which is 9+7=16.Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You can use `least()` and `greatest()` and `group by`:

```
select least(letter1, letter2), greatest(letter1, letter2), sum(score)
from t
group by least(letter1, letter2), greatest(letter1, letter2);
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also use `case` expression with aggregation :

```
select (case when letter1 < letter2 then letter1 else letter2 end) as letter1,
       (case when letter1 > letter2 then letter1 else letter2 end) as letter2,
       sum(score) as total_score
from table t
group by (case when letter1 < letter2 then letter1 else letter2 end),
         (case when letter1 > letter2 then letter1 else letter2 end);
```